# If $A \in M_n(R)$, with $R$ a P.I.D., can $A$ be put in Jordan form iff all the roots of the characteristic polynomial are in $R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, principal-ideal-domains

> If $A \in M_n(R)$, with $R$ a P.I.D., can $A$ be put in Jordan form iff all the roots of the characteristic polynomial are in $R$?

If this is false in general, is it possibly true for nilpotent matrices?

Comment: It's not true in general.  Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and consider $2 \times 2$ matrices.  Take $P = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\0&2\end{array}\right)$ and $D = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2&0\\0&4\end{array}\right)$.  Then $PDP^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2&-1\\0&4 \end{array}\right)$ but one can't possibly scale the eigenvectors (columns of $P$) to make $P$ invertible.

Comment: As for the nilpotent case, let me think about it a bit more... I can't seem to come up with a counterexample.  (It seems to be less important that the matrix is nilpotent than that its eigenvalues are all the same).

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the set of integers. If the integer $k$ is a factor of $A$ then it is a factor of $P^{-1}AP$.